# Return function type example in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, constants

Current `get()` member function in class `MyClass` is defined as below, the return type is `const int&`. My question is what would be the difference if I defined `get()` function as

> `int& get() const`

or

> `int get() const`

? And which way is recommended?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    int x;
  public:
    MyClass(int val) : x(val) {}
    const int& get() const {return x;}
};

void print (const MyClass& arg) {
  cout << arg.get() << '\n';
}

int main() {
  MyClass foo (10);
  print(foo);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: returning `int` is far simpler

Comment: Returning `int&` means the caller could say this: `myclass.get() = 42`

Comment: @selbie Before that `get()` won't compile because it's trying to bind a `const int` to `int&`.

Comment: Oh. I see that in his code now.  His original question at top suggests returning `int&` without the `const` mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with this code; logically it accomplishes more or less the same thing after the compiler inlines the get() method.

There's quite a big difference in some degenerate callers though:

```
const int *iptr = &foo.get(); // returns the address of x in the class.
```

On the other hand had you declared as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    int x;
  public:
    MyClass(int val) : x(val) {}
    const int get() const {return x;}
};

const int *iptr = &foo.get(); // Error!
```

I don't see any good reason for `int&` here. If you don't have one, people will frown on this code. Normally if people are expected to keep pointers to things around you don't return them by reference. The only reason you would want to return a pointer to a member is so that somebody can auto-pickup changes to it; and I have never seen a good use for that though I can imagine why some such thing might exist.

As for selbie's comment about assigning to it; it's a `const` reference; assigning to it is a compile time error.

Comment: Just one follow-up question, how about simply `int get()`? It seems that in this case, one cannot change x, either(just like `const` reference), right? What's your opinion about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nicholas: You are correct; int get() const is what you would normally use.